# I want to use Robot class in java applet for web browser to move and click mouse

Tags: java, mouse, awtrobot

I have created this applet, It moves mouse to 1000 pos on screen. It works as application but it does not work in applet. I have created signed applet but still it wont move mouse. What should I do to make my Robot class work from browser? My code is as below:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.AWTException;

public class s extends Applet {
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawString("Test1", 10, 10);
        }

        public void init() {
                try {
                        Robot robot = new Robot();
                        robot.mouseMove(1000,50);
                        System.out.println("code executes");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println("code failed");
                };
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an AWTException when you run the code?

Comment: Looking at this code there's something more important than my answer below: THIS IS NOT AN APPLET! http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/

Comment: thanks , i have updated it to applet. It works in applet viewer but not in browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signing alone won't give your Applet any permissions. You need to grant the `createRobot` permission to your Applet.

Check the [security tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/index.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the source-code from Robot. And I think you have to add in the constructor a ScreenDevice.